# Get "null" in IE10 localStorage if item is undefined

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, local-storage

When I get item from localStorage in Chrome, then I get a null. When I do the same in IE10, then I get an error.

Code:

```
var item = localStorage.getItem('item'); // localStorage 'item' is undefined
```

How to get a 'null' item value from localStorage in IE10, if the item is undefined?

**Update:**

A rough translation of IE10 console error from my native language:

Cannot get property "getItem" of reference, that is undefined or "NULL".

Comment: _an error_ in IE 10 ?

Comment: Error message was added in description.

Comment: Are you running on the file protocol and not http?

Comment: Yes, I run a page from local path.

Comment: @pepeevich always mention that you're running a page using `file:///`, there are a lot of things that work differently in that mode

Comment: @JuanMendes, he may not know that ;) At least me mentioned the _error_ so that one could make out things...

Comment: Juan Mendes, epascarello, thank you, I really dk it :)